# not getting response from api post

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I am working on shipping API and it giving data on postman but when I codes it gives failed to open stream:

> HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED.

Thanks anybody can help

I have pass values in header and pass parameter in body by file get contents

```php
        $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
           'phone' => '1111111111',
           'city' => 'Kota',
           'name' => 'ABC',
           'pin' => '324005',
           'address' => 'address',
           'country' => 'India',
           'contact_person' => 'name',
           'email' => 'a@gmail.com',
           'registered_name' => 'registered_name',
           'return_address' => 'return_address',
           'return_pin' => '110017',
           'return_city' => 'delhi',
           'return_state' => 'delhi',
           'return_country' => 'india',
       )
    );

    $opts = array('https'=> 
        array (
            'method' => 'POST',
               'header'=>array(
                    'authorization: Token', // removed token for protection
                    'Content-type: application/xwww-form-urlencoded',
                    'content-type: application/json',
               ),

               'content-Type' =>$postdata,
        )
    );

    $url="https://staging-express.delhivery.com/api/backend/clientwarehouse/create/";
    $context=stream_context_create($opts);
    $result=file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

Comment: A `401 UNAUTHORIZED` error probably means there's something wrong with your authorization header. I think the word `Token` in `authorization:` looks out of place. But that's just a wild guess. Sidenote: Is it wise to publish your token here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is valid:

```
$opts = array('https'=>
```

Even for an https request, it should be:

```
$opts = array('http'=>
```

Also, if I read this right, I think your:

```
'content-Type' =>$postdata,
```

should be:

```
'content' =>$postdata,
```